# Ruby can't puts concatenated string and hash element?

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm new to ruby.  The following code outputs the `rubypage` parameter:

```
cgi = CGI.new
puts cgi.params['rubypage']
```

But, as soon as I change it to this, it outputs nothing

```
cgi = CGI.new
puts cgi.params['rubypage']+"a"
```

Why does the presence of the `+"a"` cause no output?  how do I concatenate the CGI `params` element with a string?

Comment: My question is, why are you using CGI at all? It's so 90s. Instead use something like [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com), which will handle so many more of the tasks you'd have to do if you only rely on CGI. Sinatra integrates with Apache or nginx nicely via Unicorn or Passenger.

Comment: oh ok, i'll try Sinatra again..i was having a lot of issues installing it.  I read a few other complaints that cgi is 90s, so does that imply also that there are a lot of security risks with cgi?

Comment: Not necessarily security risks, you're just setting out on a path to have to do a lot more work than necessary, that is already covered by tools like Sinatra. Couple that with Haml, and you have a great prototyping and internal development system. Run under nginx or Apache using Passenger or Unicorn and you gain some industrial strength. Look at Patron when you want a more Rails-like environment. Move to Rails when you need its full power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check its docs, you will find that `CGI.params` returns a `Hash` with parameter names as its keys and parameter value *lists* as its values.  This accommodates the fact that the same query parameter can be specified multiple times.

If you want to choose just one of the values for a given parameter, then you can index into the CGI object itself, and you should be able to append a string to the result:

```
puts cgi['rubypage'] + "a"
```

or

```
puts "#{cgi['rubypage']}a"
```

If you want an array of all the values for the parameter, each with the same string appended, then you could do it like this:

```
rubypageA = cgi.params['rubypage'].map do |value|
  "#{value}a"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing should work, depending upon what's in that params hash.

Try a simple test with irb:

```
$ irb
2.1.2 :001 > "string"+"another"
 => "stringanother" 
2.1.2 :002 >
```

[Ruby's string interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation) may be of interest to you if you're going to be doing a lot of this.

Try this:

```
puts "#{cgi.params['rubypage']}a"
```

Answer (score 0):

`cgi.params['rubypage']` is an array. You cannot concatenate an string to an array. An error "TypeError: can't convert String into Array" must be logged somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your CGI script:

```
require 'cgi'

$stdout.sync = true  #Do not buffer output to STDOUT
$stderr.reopen($stdout)  #Send errors to stdout(which goes to your browser)
```

Then the error messages will be sent to your browser, e.g.:

```
/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/myprog.rb:17:in `': no implicit conversion
of String into Array (TypeError)
```

Which is the same error you will get if you try to do the following in a regular Ruby program:

```
[1, 2, 3] + 'a'
```

> I read a few other complaints that cgi is 90s, so does that imply also
>   that there are a lot of security risks with cgi?

There are security risks with any website.  CGI is very lightweight, so if you want to do simple things(or custom things) it is fine.  It's a good introduction to web programming.